# Elm: How to log inside a foldl

Tags: elm, foldleft

I have the following code:

```
findPerson name peeps = List.foldl
    (\a b -> case b of
        Just _ -> b
        Nothing -> if a.name == name then
            Just a
            else Nothing
    ) Nothing peeps
```

I would like to log the values of `a` and `b` inside the `foldl`. I've tried:

```
findPerson : String -> List Person -> Maybe Person
findPerson name peeps = List.foldl
    (\a b ->
        Debug.log(a)
        Debug.log(b)
        case b of
            Just _ -> b
            Nothing -> if a.name == name then
                Just a
                else Nothing
    ) Nothing peeps
```

However, this throws an error

```
I am looking for one of the following things:

a closing paren ')'
whitespace`
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I log the values inside `foldl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a let in block for debugging.

```
let
    _ = Debug.log "a" a
    _ = Debug.log "b" b
in
    case b of
...
```

---

A function (or lambda) can only return once.
Debug.log returns the second argument unchanged, so you have to pattern match it against something - and because you don't need the argument twice, but the side effect of Debug.log, you can pattern match it against `_` (ignore).

Answer (score 2):

You can also put the `Debug.log` directly inside the `case statement`, or inside the `if statement` for the same reasons @farmio mentioned :) - Like so :

```
findPerson name peeps = List.foldl
    (\a b -> 
        case ( Debug.log "inspect b: " b ) of
           Just _ -> 
              b
           Nothing -> 
              if ( Debug.log "person name is: " a.name )  == name then
                  Just a
              else 
                  Nothing
    ) Nothing peeps
```

Not as clean, but sometimes more useful because is more compact.